# jquery count with each clone instance and display count

Tags: jquery, clone, increment, decrement

**Task** I am cloning a div.cloneable with the following function:

```
$('#addBtn').click(function() {
 var c = $('.cloneable:first').clone(true);
 $('.cloneable:last').after(c);
}
});
```

Then, after I clone .cloneable, I can remove any instance using this function:

```
$('.dltBtn').click(function() {
$(this).closest('.cloneable').remove();
$('.dltBtn').attr('disabled',($('.cloneable').length
```

**Problem:**  I have a line of html in div.cloneable: "Adobe Flash Streaming Service #1".  How do I increment/decrement and display the #1, increment when I clone so that it says #2, *3, etc., and decrementing when I remove the div.cloneable element?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're probably looking for is the innerHTML property of the div object. Then you can split the resultant string on #, take the second element, and parseInt() on it, then increment it. Then set the innerHTML back.

Like so:

```
var inner = c.innerHTML;
var arr = inner.split("#");
var numString = arr[1];
var myNum = parseInt(numString);
myNum ++;
c.innerHTML = "Adobe Flash Streaming Service #" + myNum
```

or shorter:

```
 c.innerHTML = "Adobe Flash Streaming Service #" + (parseInt(c.innerHTML.split("#")[1]) + 1)
```